# Flutter merge multiple streams flutter to perform OR queries in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, rxdart

In this code I try to retrieve data match this logic: `if (title == query || subtitle == query)`. Here my code using `MergeStream` of `RxDart`:

```
  //if (title == query)
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> searchProgramsByTitle(String query) async* {
    if (query.length == 0) {
      yield* fireStore.collection('programs').orderBy('listened', descending: true).snapshots();
    }
    else {
      yield* fireStore.collection('programs').where('title', isEqualTo: query).orderBy('listened', descending: true).snapshots();
    }
  }
  
  //if (subtitle == query)
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> searchProgramsBySubtitle(String query) async* {
    if (query.length == 0) {
      yield* fireStore.collection('programs').orderBy('listened', descending: true).snapshots();
    }
    else {
      yield* fireStore.collection('programs').where('subtitle', isEqualTo: query).orderBy('listened', descending: true).snapshots();
    }
  }
  
  // OR query
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> searchPrograms(String query) async* {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream1 = searchProgramsByTitle(query);
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream2 = searchProgramsBySubtitle(query);
    yield* MergeStream([stream1, stream2]);
  }
```

`searchProgramsByTitle` and `searchProgramsBySubtitle` work fine seperately. But `searchPrograms` doesn't work. What am I missing ?

Comment: *"But searchPrograms doesn't work"* - explain `doesn't work`

Comment: It does not return firestore data. If I change ```MergeStream([stream1]);``` or ```MergeStream([stream2]);```. It's ok.

Comment: so both streams are not empty, does the example from https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/MergeStream-class.html work at you? what if you replace those two input streams with your ones? what do you see?

Comment: The final data is 1. I think I get your point. So how do I fix it ?

Comment: [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html) maybe? the docs say: *"Merges the given Streams into one Stream sequence by using the `combiner` function whenever any of the source stream sequences emits an item."*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to these lovely answers of pskink. I manage to solve this problem:

```
  Stream<List> searchPrograms(String query) async* {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream1 = searchProgramsByTitle(query);
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream2 = searchProgramsBySubtitle(query);
    yield* rx.CombineLatestStream.combine2(stream1, stream2, (QuerySnapshot a, QuerySnapshot b) => [...a.docs.map((e) => e.id), ...b.docs.map((e) => e.id)]);
  }
```